# Problem with input and return in python app for count words

Tags: python

i'm just starting to learn now and i have been doing some exercises trying to add some inputs to the basics functions i have made .

right now i have this code.

```
print("This is an app calculate the lenght of a word")

def String_Lenght(word):
    if type(word) == int:
        return "Integers can't be counted"
    elif type(word) == float:
        return "floats can't be counted"
    else:
        return len(word)
word = input("enter the word")
print(String_Lenght(word))
```

The problem is that i get the len of the word but i'm not getting the messages for int and floats in the case when i introduce one, which would be the error here.

Thanks/

Comment: `input()` always returns a string. If you input `5` it is just a string of value `'5'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: You can use a try/except statement in order to see whether the input can get converted into an int / a float.

Comment: @quant  You can check my answer  below . I think I do porvide a more elegant solution .

Answer (score 1):

You can use ast.literal_eval() function to evaluate the string to either the integer or the floating point number and then use your code to count the length of the string.

```
from ast import literal_eval
print("This is an app calculate the length of a word")
def String_Lenght(word):
    try:
        word = literal_eval(word)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    if type(word) == int:
        return "Integers can't be counted"
    elif type(word) == float:
        return "floats can't be counted"
    else:
        return len(word)
word = input("enter the word")
print(String_Lenght(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read 'word' is always a string in python 3+.

so `type(word)` is always string. hence you would get  the length. Check the output below for your program. i used hard breakpoint using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

instead of trying to check type(word). I think you should convert string to int / float.

I think converting to float is a best option .

This issue is in python 3. as all data from input is string. you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers).

```
$ python t.py
This is an app calculate the lenght of a word
enter the word1
> /Users/sesh/tmp/t.py(6)String_Lenght()
-> if type(word) == int:
(Pdb) word
'1'
(Pdb) type (word)
<class 'str'>
(Pdb) int(word)
1
(Pdb) float(word)
1.0
(Pdb) int('asdfads)
*** SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
(Pdb)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(String_Lenght(word))
  File "t.py", line 6, in String_Lenght
    if type(word) == int:
  File "t.py", line 6, in String_Lenght
    if type(word) == int:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 51, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 70, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
(qsic-api-django)
sesh at Seshs-MacBook-Pro in ~/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this problem is in Python input function always return str type.
So in your code type(word) always return True.
You should change your code to this.

```
print("This is an app calculate the lenght of a word")

def String_Lenght(word):
    if word.isdigit():
        return "Integers can't be counted"
    elif word.replace(".", "", 1).isdigit():
        return "floats can't be counted"
    else:
        return len(word)


word = input("enter the word")
print(String_Lenght(word))
```